# PDFsharp: How to place next text after XTextFormatter?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to create PDF documents. `XTextFormatter` is being used to wrap the text if it is going beyond specified y co-ordinate. However, I want to place "Phone number" just after the "tf.DrawString" text ends.

Currently, texts are getting overlapped as attached  [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OLx2.png).

```
 var dy = 13;
 graphics.DrawString("Delivery Location: ", font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(20, 111));
 graphics.DrawString(comp_name, font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(20, 111+ dy));
 XRect rect = new XRect(20, 124, 200, 34);
 graphics.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
 tf.DrawString("This is just test. This is just test. This is just test. This is just test.",
 font,
 XBrushes.Black,
 new XRect(rect.X + 5, rect.Y, rect.Width - 5, 34), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
 graphics.DrawString("Phone Number: " + comp_phone1, font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(20, 136+ dy));
 graphics.DrawString("GST: " + comp_gst, font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(20, 149+ dy));
 graphics.DrawString("PAN: " + comp_pan, font, XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(20, 159+ dy));
```

Comment: @KJ, updated my code as requested. text overlapping issue is still there.

Comment: lines wrap is dynamic field, it takes input from the users, so we cannot guess how much lines wrap can take place.

Comment: There is a version with feedback. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `XTextFormatter` is just a demo to get you started. Upgrade it according to your needs.

An upgraded version can be found here:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3192

This version returns the height needed for the text. You can add more text below.

Comment: XTextFormatterEx2 tf = new XTextFormatterEx2(graphics);
                int cIndex;
                double ndheight;
                XRect rect = new XRect(20, 124, 200, double.MaxValue);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
                tf.PrepareDrawString(text,
                font,
                rect, out cIndex, out ndheight);
                rect = new XRect(20, 124, 200, ndheight);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
                tf.DrawString(XBrushes.Black, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

Comment: same error with above code. tf's text is overlapping with the next text.

Comment: You have to use `ndheight` to prevent overlapping. Comments are no good place to share sample code.